# How do I make :after box same size as parent and responsive? transform: scale(1) works, but why?

Tags: html, css

I'm styling a box with a simple gradient background and overlaying it with an SVG background image, like this:

HTML:

```
<div class="card-image-none">
  <img src="/graphics/16-9.png" class="w-100 img-fluid">
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.card-image-none {
    height: auto;
    background-image: linear-gradient(to bottom, rgba(0,0,0,0.05) 0%,rgba(0,0,0,0.2) 100%);
}

.card-image-none:after {
    content: "";
    display: block;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    background-image: url('/fontawesome/svgs/solid/quote-right.svg');
    background-size: 40%;
    background-position: 50% 50%;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    opacity: 0.1;
}
```

BTW, **image 16-9.png** is a transparent box that's used to maintain a specific (and responsive) dimension to the box. The problem is that the overlay image defined in `card-image-none:after` doesn't stay confined within the parent box because of `height: 100%`. It can sometimes look like this:

[image: overflowing box]

But if I add `transform: scale(1);` to **card-image-none**, then it stays confined within the parent box, like this:

```
.card-image-none {
    height: auto;
    background-image: linear-gradient(to bottom, rgba(0,0,0,0.05) 0%,rgba(0,0,0,0.2) 100%);
    transform: scale(1);
}
```

[image: correct placement]

It works as I want when I include `transform: scale(1)`, and I'm not sure why or if there's a better way to do this without transform.

Comment: Without seeing more of your code, I'm guessing it's because you are using `position: absolute` on your `:after` element, but the parent `.card-image-none` does not  have a position set. Try adding `position: relative` to your `.card-image-none {}` styles. Absolutely position elements position themselves to the nearest parent with a `position` set.

Comment: @disinfor OMG, how could I forget that!! That's exactly why I couldn't get it to work without the transform option. After adding the missing "position: relative" to .card-image-non, it worked. But how do I make your comment the answer to my question?

Comment: Added an answer for you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like it's because you didn't add a `position` property to your main element `.card-image-none`.

Because you are using `absolute` positioning for your `:after` element, it will position itself to the nearest element with a position set.

Just add `position: relative` to the `.card-image-none`

```
.card-image-none {
    position: relative;
    height: auto;
    background-image: linear-gradient(to bottom, rgba(0,0,0,0.05) 0%,rgba(0,0,0,0.2) 100%);
}
```

A little more background to the specific query:

Adding `transform: scale(0)` worked because [transform](https://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/t/transform/) creates a new positioning context (very last bullet on the page), just like adding `position: relative`

Comment: Thanks! Can't believe I forgot to add that, but, it worked!